# Grid content doesn't match the grid layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Basically, I'm building a grid in HTML/CSS using flexbox and grids to get the desired layout.

I've been working on it in VSCode and I've managed to make it look the way I desire (see img below).
[image: How It Should Look]

my issue comes when this get rendered inside WP, for some reason the boxes do not expand to fit the size of the grid layout creating some weird gaps in the content. (see below)
[image: The white part should not be here]

I used the grid overlay and I noticed that the grid is the right size, is just that the box is not expanding properly.
[image: box is not totally expanded]

I'm not really sure what the issue is here, I have tried adjusting the layout, the padding, etc.

**HTML**

```css
main{
width: 100vw;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around
}

.grid-section{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 250px;
    background: #313131;
    color: rgb(211, 168, 168);
    font-size: 15px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
justify-content: space-around
}


#grid{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(32, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: 12% 44% 44% 0%
} 

.box {
display: flex;
flex-basis: 100%;
}


/*top*/
.box:nth-child(1){
    background: #9dcbe9;
    grid-column: 1/33;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    padding: 5px;
}
/*left*/
.box:nth-child(2){
    background: #eed875;
    grid-column: 1/6;
    grid-row: 2/4;
}
/*right*/
.box:nth-child(3){
    background: #c97eec;
    grid-column:28/33;
    grid-row: 2/4;
}
/*middle long*/
.box:nth-child(4){
    background: #9de99d;
    grid-column: 6/28;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}


/*mini boxes*/
.box:nth-child(5){
    background: #ffa569;
    grid-column: 6/9;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}
.box:nth-child(6){
    background: #584905;
    grid-column: 9/14;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}
.box:nth-child(7){
    background: #560b79;
    grid-column: 14/17;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}
.box:nth-child(8){
    background: #00ff00;
    grid-column: 17/20;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}
.box:nth-child(9){
    background: #0a9ed8;
    grid-column: 20/23;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}
.box:nth-child(10){
    background: #5802e2;
    grid-column: 23/28;
    grid-row: 3/4;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<title> flexBox testing</title>  
  
<body>

    <main>
    <div id="grid" class="grid-section">    
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-content">n1</div> 
        </div>   
            
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-content">n2</div> 
        </div> 
 
        <div class="box"> 
            <div class="box-content">n3</div> 
        </div>    
 
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-content">n4</div> 
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-content">n5</div> 
        </div>
       
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-content">n6</div>
        </div> 
 
        <div class="box"> 
            <div class="box-content">n7</div> 
        </div>    
 
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-content">n8</div> 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-content">n9</div> 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-content">n10</div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </main>    

</body>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well the code in your question works. Something changes when you run the code in WP. Perhaps some WP code overrides what you have. Can't really help you without seeing the WP code.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
      grid-row-gap: 0.5rem;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .grid-item {
      background-color: #999;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 30px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">6</div>
    <div class="grid-item">7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">8</div>
    <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Comment: Use the above snippet for CSS Grid ! and change the properties if required !